# Issue with converting data string to UTF8

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I am getting some datas with JSON but when I get data the `name`s tring is something like this :

```
{
    code = 200;
    found = 1;
    name = "\\u0635\\u0641\\u062d\\u0647 \\u0631\\u0633\\u0645\\u06cc \\u0633\\u0627\\u06cc\\u062a \\u0648\\u0631\\u0632\\u0634 \\u06f3";
}
```

How can fix it ? I tried to convert it to UTF8 encoding and still nothing ! I have to say the URL works fine in Safari with UTF8 encoding

Here is my code :

```
   let userURL: String = "https://myurl.com/xxx"
        let ut8 = userURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:ut8!)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Check if data was received successfully
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                       print(jsonResult)
    }

.....
}
```

> Problem Solved: There was a problem in server , now fixed

Comment: That's not the JSON string, it's the dictionary representation. Are you sure that the JSON contains those Unicode tokens?

Comment: @vadian I just edit my Q title

Comment: Don't convert and assign the `name` string to a `text` property of a UILabel. What happens?

Comment: What's your issue here? It seems you have successfully received your JSON data as NSDictionary. Try `print(jsonResult["code"], jsonResult["found"], jsonResult["name"])`.

Comment: @vadian same thing , actually i pass this string to a lable

Answer (score 0):

It's just what the `print` method outputs and it sometimes has problem with encoding. You should be fine when render those text in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the data string into UTF8 string in Swift

```
yourNSStringObject.utf8
```

To convert the data string into UTF8 string  in Objective C use

```
[yourNSStringObject UTF8String];
```